# Book about people finding out they are on some kind of space 'ark'

Tags: story-identification, novel, soft-sci-fi

Looking for a 1960s book about people who think they are exploring a planet until they find they are on a huge space 'ark' going somewhere that has been travelling for generations.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! This would be improved if you could [edit] in some more details you remember about the plot and add in anything else you may remember.

Comment: This is either a common theme or I swear I've seen it before being asked here.

Comment: This is way too broad. There have been dozens (and probably hundreds) of books about people discovering they're actually on a generation ship.

Comment: This question would be improved by going through the checklists here ; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common science fiction trope, so there are multiple works that fit this limited description.  However, I am going to suggest *[Non-Stop](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/384579.Non_Stop)* by Brian Aldiss, from 1958.  It was also published under the title *Starship*.

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Stop_(novel)):

> The novel's protagonist, Roy Complain, lives in a culturally-primitive tribe in which curiosity is discouraged and life is solitary, poor, nasty, brutish and short. With a small group, he leaves his home and ventures into uncharted territory. The consequent discoveries will change his perception of the entire universe.
>
> Complain's small tribe roam nomadically through corridors overrun by vegetation. After his wife is kidnapped, a tribal priest named Marapper encourages Complain to join a furtive expedition into the unexplored corridors. It is Marapper's belief that they are all living on board a moving spacecraft and that if they can reach the control room, they will gain command of the entire gargantuan vessel.

Comment: Sure, but it could just as easily be https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7617141-the-star-seekers, Thirteen to Centaurus, Phoenix Without Ashes or a dozen others.

Comment: If you're going to quote a source can you provide a link back to where you got it from? I've edited it in this time because it was easy to find but you should be including this information by default.